# Refresh Windows 8 without metro UI?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-8-refresh

I would like to refresh windows 8, because no Modern UI app will run. I have degraded start menu and search behavior. The first misbehavior I noticed was the "out of box experience" ran on system boot. I noticed this OOBE again after changing my password (before giving remote access to someone for help on this issue). The system is in an equally bad state with minimal safe mode boot.

I was hoping to refresh the system without losing all my applications/data, but the only path to execute a refresh seems to be within the Modern UI PC Settings.

I tried using the installation disc to initiate a refresh, but was informed that the system disk was locked. When running the disk within windows, I do not have the option to refresh.

Comment: Your inability to run Modern UI applications shouldn't effect your ability to access the systems settings interface through the Modern UI to start the refresh process.

Comment: I completely agree that it should not, but it is my experience, and part of what I thought made the question interesting. There is no apparent way to use this feature in the control panel or powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System refresh is available from the boot menu, you can access it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> during boot.

The disk was locked because system was hibernated. Win8 uses hybrid shutdown, i.e. it doesn't shut down completely - OS kills most processes and enters a state similar to hibernation to boot up faster. Reboot always uses complete shutdown. To perform a single full shutdown (not reboot) without disabling hybrid shutdown completely use the following command in the *Run* window or console:

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to make sense. I will try this tonight.

Comment: Shift+F8 did not initiate a boot menu for me, and that shutdown command did did not prevent the 'disk is locked' error when attempting to refresh from installation media. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: Try `shutdown /r /o`, it should reboot directly to that menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your PC from the boot menu as well, I think it's the F8 key at boot, but I feel like Microsoft changed it. then it's in advanced options.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the boot menu by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting Restart from the power icon. I found this option on [About.com](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm) and it allowed me to refresh despite not being able to get to 'PC Settings' where one would normally kickoff a refresh. I did not find a way to initiate a refresh from the command line.